# XCode 'Unable to install app' due to entitlement mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode

Since migration of developer account, I get this error when I try to debug the app using XCode.

```
Unable to install "MyApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
-- 
  This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.


 Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
 Code: -402652994
```

I don't know where to look and fix the missing entitlements. Tried everything mentioned in other answers for similar question but didn't work. I want to know if there is a way to fix it without deleting the app from the phone?

Comment: Did you change the app's bundle identifier?

Comment: No, I did not. Just changed the developer account so have new XCode generic profile

Comment: Does the generic profile have the exact same values? If the team ID is different it might not match what you already had in the device. Try using a non-generic profile.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you tell me how to check that?

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue. I had an earlier version on the device and that appears to have created the conflict. I removed the old version and reinstalled the new and the error was resolved.